# Update user profile information from functions.php

Tags: php, functions, user-meta

I have the following function in my functions.php file:-

```
function apply_for_job() {

    $job_id = $_GET['job_id'];

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $prev_value = get_field('applied_jobs');

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'applied_jobs', $job_id);


}
add_filter('init' ,'apply_for_job');
```

When I load: http://distinct.dev/apply_for_job/?job_id=323

This updates 'applied_jobs' field to: 323 as expected.

However, when I go on my user profile page it sets the value to 'NULL'

Any ideas why?

I've got it working as follows:-

```
function apply_for_job() {

    if (!empty($_GET['job_id'])) {
        $job_id = $_GET['job_id'];
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $prev_value = get_field('applied_jobs');

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'applied_jobs', $job_id);


}
if (!empty($_GET['job_id'])) {
add_filter('init' ,'apply_for_job');
}
```

Although this is probably not the 'standard' way

Comment: Not sure what the big picture is, but note that you're running this on every page load (front-end and back-end) even when there's no `job_id` GET parameter. Your `$prev_value` is also not used.

Comment: I've got it working @birgire - although I'm sure this isn't the correct way in doing this